# Why are there so many downvoted entries on Forvo for the Russian word for "Ukraine"?

Tags: electronic-resources, russian, forvo

Forvo's entries for the Russian word for "Ukraine", [Украина](https://forvo.com/word/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0/#ru) include approximately 11 entries with a negative net vote, some of them with a net score of -2, and including pronunciations by Russians and by Ukrainians.

Is this because there are lots of awful pronunciations of this word? Or has hostility between Russia and Ukraine spilled out into petty downvoting on this language learning resource? Should I distrust voting scores on this site?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about language learning.

Comment: To further clarify my closure: I see two questions here: 1) Are the down-voted pronunciations correct? This is a question for [Russian.SE](http://russian.stackexchange.com/).  2) Are these downvotes motivated by political malice? This question is off-topic on the entire SE network, as it's about motivations.

Comment: If you want to re-work this question to focus on your last sentence, "Should I distrust voting scores on [Forvo]?", using this word as an example, it might be salvageable for this site. But it might be tricky to make it not primarily-opinion-based.